# linear regression in r using differenced response variable

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to run this code

```
 r2<-lm(diff(Y)~.,data=credit.train)
```

Now, I get the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = diff(Y) ~ ., data = credit.train,  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 't')

I understand that on differencing, number of rows of Y is decreasing by 1 which is not happening for the X variables. Any idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Well, do you want to regress the differences in Y against the original values of your predictors or the new values of your predictors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend at one end or the other (with loss of one set of predictors) using the `I()`-function

From the `?lm` page:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(I(c(diff(weight),NA)) ~ group)  # no error
```

Also no error just with:

```
lm.D9 <- lm( c(diff(weight),NA) ~ group)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to regress the increase of value `Y`, namely `Y(n+1)-Y(n)` against some variable `x(n)` or `t(n)` etc., so just filter out the last row from your data frame:

```
  r2 <- lm(diff(Y) ~ ., data = credit.train[1:(length(credit.train)-1), ])
```